# Custom Serviceprovider not found

Tags: laravel, service-provider

I tried to implement a custom service provider and facade to my project:

**1. Creation of folders for class to be included and facade**
/app/Helpers/GeoLocation.php
/app/Facades/GeoLocation.php

**2. Creation of class to be provided: Helpers/Geolocation.php**

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class GeoLocation {
    public function test($text) {
        return 'Cool ' . $text;
    }
}
```

**3. Cration of Facade for GeoLocation: Facades/Geolocation.php**

```
<?php namespace Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class GeoLocation extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'geolocation'; }
}
```

**4. Adding GeoLocationServiceProvider: /Providers/GeoLocationServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GeoLocationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        App::bind('geolocation', function()
        {
            return new \Helpers\GeoLocation();
        });
    }
}
```

**5. Adding information to app.php**

```
/*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider',
```

**6. Adding alias**

```
'GeoLocation' => 'Facades\GeoLocation'
```

After that I executed `composer dump-autoload` and used the new service provider:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return GeoLocation::test('test');
});
```

But it returns the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'App\Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found
in ProviderRepository.php line 150
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 131
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 116
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at ProviderRepository->createProvider() in ProviderRepository.php line 75
at ProviderRepository->load() in Application.php line 446
at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 15
at RegisterProviders->bootstrap() in Application.php line 174
at Application->bootstrapWith() in Kernel.php line 199
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 110
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 53
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

I have no clue what I missed out. Is it about the folders?

Comment: please attach your GeoLocationServiceProvider as well

Comment: I just edited the question and added the provider

Comment: try 'Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider', because your service providers is not under App namespace

Comment: I adapted the path in the app.php to 'Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider' but now the error is `Class 'Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: did you add the GeoLocationServiceProvider to you composer autoload ?

Comment: When I run `composer update` the following error comes up: `Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Providers\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found in /home/vagrant/mfserver/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150`

Comment: No. How would I need to add this? This is the content right now `"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "database"
  ],
  "psr-4": {
   "App\\": "app/"
  }
 },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73843/discussion-between-terry-low-and-isarfaktor).

Comment: Thank you Terry... The missing link was as you said in the Service Provider register function. I need to use \App::bind and not App::bind